# Error uploading ShinyApp when using Highcharter

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I've created a Shiny dashboard which is using Highcharter. When I try to upload it to the Shiny Server I get this error:

"Warning: Error in dyn.load: unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/igraph/libs/igraph.so': libglpk.so.36: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

The iGraph dependency for Highcharter should automatically install itself, so not sure what the problem is. I've also tried referencing iGraph in the library() call.

Has anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: Are both of those packages installed in your server instance?

Comment: Calling both of the packages in the library() function should install the packages if they're not already right?

Comment: No. That just loads them into the session to be used. You first need to install it into that instance of Shiny Server.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, you are encouraged to mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the package is installed on the instance of Shiny Server. The Library() function does not install missing packages, install.packages() does this. But you would not want to have install.packages() directly in your code since it will attempt to install the package for each session (unless you placed it in an if{} statement that first checked the availability of the package).